# Python give *args default value

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments

Inside my class I have:

```
def refresh(self, func = None, *args):
    if not func:
        return
    new_data = func(*args)
    self.set_text(new_data)
```

But I have 2 problems:

1. What if `func` doesn't take any parameters? Why can't I do `*args = None`?
   like I want to do something like this:

   ```
   def refresh(self, func = None, *args = None):
       if not func:
           return
       if *args:
           new_data = func(*args)
       else:
           new_data = func() # func doesn't take any parameters
       self.set_text(new_data)
   ```
2. When I try to run my code before the edits I get:

   > TypeError: function takes 0 positional arguments but 1 were given

   Why is that?

Here is my main:

```
def hello_world():
    return 'hello'

tmp2 = LLabel('Hi There!')
tmp2.refresh(hello_world, None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error "takes 0 positional arguments but 1 were given" because here

> ```
> tmp2.refresh(hello_world, None)
> ```

the original implementation of `refresh` will not pass *no argument* to `hello_world`, but *one argument*, namely `None`.

Instead, just don't provide any further arguments to `refresh`:

```
tmp2.refresh(hello_world)
```

Then, inside `refresh`, `args` will be an empty tuple and `func(*args)` will be equivalent to `func()`.

The alternative implementation of `refresh`, which you have attempted to use, is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

None is an argument of `NoneType`. You can try it simply by running the `hello_world` function by itself.

```
def hello_world():
    return 'hello'
hello_world(None)
```

Which will result in the following error: `TypeError: hello_world() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`.

Hence run the `refresh` method, with only one argument - the function you want to pass in:

```
def hello_world():
    return 'hello'
tmp2 = LLabel('Hi There!')
tmp2.refresh(hello_world)
```

Therefore the original `refresh` method can stay the same:

```
def refresh(self, func = None, *args):
    if not func:
        return
    new_data = func(*args)
    self.set_text(new_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

`*args` is of type `tuple`.

If your function doesn't take parameters, that means you have an empty tuple `args`. And an empty tuple is a **falsy** value in Python.

So your function can look like this:

```py
def refresh(self, func = None, *args):
    if not func:
        return
    if args:  # evaluates to True if not empty
        new_data = func(*args)
    else:
        new_data = func() # func doesn't take any parameters
    self.set_text(new_data)
```

The unpacking operator `*` is not needed in the `if` condition. It is actually a **SyntaxError**.

If you now call your `refresh` method, passing a function that doesn't take any parameters, you just need to pass the function to the method:

```py
def hello_world():
    return 'hello'

tmp2 = LLabel('Hi There!')
tmp2.refresh(hello_world)
```

Comment: Thanks, but do I really need that if condition?

Comment: Like @mkrieger1 said, you don't need the `if args` condition, as nothing will be passed to `func(*args)` if `args` is empty. I did it just for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

In the call to refresh, you can just omit any additional arguments:

```
tmp2.refresh(hello_world)
```

This will cause the `args` variable within the function to be set an empty tuple, so the call to `fn` results in an empty argument list.